# How can I set/get Session if using vertx's WebApiServiceGen?

Tags: java, vert.x

I'm using vertx 4.2.0 and I have implemented @WebApiServiceGen successfully. However, I want to get/set Session but I see that there are ServiceRequest and ServiceResponse. Is there any way to customize or get/set Session ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ServiceRequest` contains part of the data available in `RoutingContext`, because a `RoutingContext` object cannot be sent over the bus.

If you need extra data from the session, configure a `extraPayloadMapper`.

See [The ServiceRequest data object](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web-api-service/java/#_the_servicerequest_data_object) section in docs.

Comment: But I also want to set data within Session

Comment: I know Web API Service module is still Technical Preview, but I want to customize get/set Session if possible. If there is no solution, I think I should use the routing context for those APIs handling get/set session.

Comment: I don't believe setting data to `RoutingContext` in general and `Session` in particular is currently possible. As a workaround, you could put the data in a shared data map and then retrieve this data in an additional handler that is attached to the route.

Comment: I have done like you said and it has worked. Personally, it's an acceptable solution but it's not good because it makes my codes not clean. Thank you for your answer

Comment: Do not hesitate to file an issue for enhancement